# MS SQL - Count by range of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database of aircraft flight track data that cross certain points. I'm looking at the altitude that the aircraft crossed these points at and trying to bin them by every 100 ft. The altitudes range from about 2000 ft to 15000 ft so I want a way to do this that automates the 100 ft increments.  So I want to have the crossing point, a range (say 2000-2100 ft), and the count. And the next line is the crossing point, the next range (2100-2200 ft), and the count, and so on.

I'm still a SQL newbie so any help to get me pointed in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edited for clarity - I have nothing. I want a column with my crossing location, another with the altitude range, and a third with the count. I'm just not sure to bin the data so it will give me the ranges in 100 ft. increments.

Comment: What SQL code do you have implemented so far? Whenever it comes to automating a process, it's first essential to know how your process works manually.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the sample data as DDL + DML and desired result.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I've really come up blank so far so there isn't really anything that I've got written to do this yet.

Comment: Please provide your table structure, some sample Data and expected output.

Comment: You can create the buckets using `col - col % 100` and then group by it.

Comment: Divide by 100: 2000-2099 divided by 100 is 20; 2100-2199 divided by 100 is 21 and so on.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: This works as long as altitude is stored as an INT :-)

Comment: @dnoeth: Yes, with decimals one would use `FLOOR` to get the integer part of the division result.

Comment: Do you have source data?  Can you share some example records?  Can you show us who you want those sample records presented at the end of the process?  Can you detail what steps you have taken so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a calculated column for the AltitudeBucket. This is automatically calculated. (This technique is often used for loading dimension tables into data warehouses.)

In this case, having the AltitudeBucket as a calculated column means you can do calculations on it and use it in WHERE clauses.

Create and populate a table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TrackPoint
(
    TrackPointID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CrossingPoint nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    AltitudeFeet int NOT NULL
        CHECK (AltitudeFeet BETWEEN 1 AND 60000),
    AltitudeBucket AS (AltitudeFeet / 100) * 100 PERSISTED NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TrackPoint (CrossingPoint, AltitudeFeet)
    VALUES
        (N'Paris', 12772),
        (N'Paris', 12765),
        (N'Paris', 32123),
        (N'Toulouse', 5123),
        (N'Toulouse', 6123),
        (N'Toulouse', 6120),
        (N'Lyon', 15000),
        (N'Lyon', 15010);
```

Display what's in the table.

```
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.TrackPoint;
```

[image]

Run a SELECT query to calculate summarised counts.

```
SELECT CrossingPoint, AltitudeBucket, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
    FROM dbo.TrackPoint
    GROUP BY CrossingPoint, AltitudeBucket
    ORDER BY CrossingPoint, AltitudeBucket;
```

[image]

If you want to display the altitude range.

```
SELECT CrossingPoint, AltitudeBucket, CAST(AltitudeBucket AS nvarchar) + N'-' + CAST(AltitudeBucket + 99 AS nvarchar) AS 'AltitudeBucketRange', COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
    FROM dbo.TrackPoint
    GROUP BY CrossingPoint, AltitudeBucket
    ORDER BY CrossingPoint, AltitudeBucket;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you're attempting to automate any kind of process, you first must design the algorithm for the process to successfully execute *manually*. To begin, pick out the smallest piece of this process: returning a count of altitudes between range x and x+100. So when x = 2000, you want to return all records between 2000 and 2100.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AltitudesTable
WHERE altitude >= 2000 AND altitude < 2100;
```

The above code works for one case: 2000 <= x < 2100.
To "automate," or loop through all cases, try using T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @x INT = 2000;
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM AltitudesTable)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AltitudesTable
    WHERE altitude >= @x AND altitude < @x+100;
    @x = @x+100;
END
```

Respectfully, your requirements are not solidly defined, so I had to make some assumptions regarding table structure and datatypes.

Comment: Do it without the WHILE or Cursor.

Comment: @mxix This solution is functional in the sense that it automates OP's task as required. Frankly I don't see the reason to downvote this/ provide an ambiguous comment without a better suggestion. I'm all ears if you have a means of looping and keeping track of the current range without a cursor or while. :)

Comment: It is not ambiguous. Don't do Loops unless you have to. You have multiple options, one was mentioned in the question comments, the other answer shows an example. Or you could solve this with a Tally Table.